# Choosing Character ranges in unicode

Tags: python, unicode, character-encoding, python-unicode

Say i want to parse through a string and remove any characters above a certain range, for example if I wanted to remove all of the emojis in a string. An example of where this is done is printing text out in IDLE in python, where the BMP range does not cover emojis and will spit out an error if you try it. A common solution to this error online is:

```
"".join((i if ord(i) < 10000 else '\ufffd' for i in s))
```

Where 10000 is the character limit, and all characters above this limit will change into the unicode replacement character �.

Why 10000? [Another solution online with this exact code uses 65000](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/6xnnxd/nonbmp_charactersemojis/dmiypzf/?st=jshhv5fg&sh=1ba90a36)

How would I choose what character limit I want? In my exact situation, for Python 3?

I suppose you'd base it off of some python documentation saying the BMP limit, but I cant find that, so what is a realistic limit that would include all important characters such as numbers and letters such that, for example a sentence including out of range characters, would still be understandable?

Thanks, sorry for bad English I cant explain my problems very well

Comment: What is your "exact situation"?  What are your criteria for deciding whether or not you want to try to render a character?

Comment: Exactly. We don't know what your requirements are. That said, my limit would be 55296 or hex \uD800.

Comment: The code you saw probably didn't use 10000 but 0x10000 which is totally different, it's a hex number that's 65536 in decimal.

Comment: There are characters above U+FFFF that are non emoji, and you should care about composing characters: you should remove the entire grapheme (so codepoint linked to the character you want to remove). -- I recommend against using a number, but I would remove character of some type (check `unicodedata` module).